# Prune List (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am generating a String List on the fly, Filling List(A) with strings from a dynamic List(B), but I can not seem to prune the list. *i.e, If String "bob" is removed from List(B), List(A) does not remove the String "bob".

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

void MyMethod(){
    if (PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList ().Length == 0){
        print ("No Rooms to Display");
    }else{
        foreach (RoomInfo roomInfo in PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList ()){
            if(!CompleteRoomList.Contains(roomInfo.name)){
            CompleteRoomList.Add (roomInfo.name);
            }else{
             //Prune CompleteRoomList to match roominfo.name
            CompleteRoomList.Remove (roomInfo.name);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code where you actually remove a string? Since those are regular lists list A will not automatically remove an item from List B. You have to explicitly remove the same object from both lists if it should be removed from both lists.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D List A is controlled Automatically by Photon, I just made a List that, grabs the strings in the Photon list  "List A". List B just needs to reflect List A, whether it add or remove.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D If I knew the code that I needed to complete the action, I would have not, posted for help. That is like asking why my solution is not working.I made it clear "imo" that I was seeking insight on the issue. Gunnar B. Made it clear that I was over thinking, thus I marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially List B shall be a reference to List A, correctly? In that case

```
listB = listA;
```

will do that.

Example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ListTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<string> listA = new List<string>();
    List<string> listB;

    void Start()
    {
        listA.Add("a");
        listA.Add("b");

        listB = listA;

        listB.Add("c");
        listB.Remove("a");

        listA.Add("d");

        Debug.Log("List A:");
        foreach(string item in listA)
            Debug.Log(item);

        Debug.Log("List B:");
        foreach(string item in listB)
            Debug.Log(item);
    }
}
```

The output will be this:

```
List A:
b
c
d
List B:
b
c
d
```

Comment: ah! I always tend to make simple task more difficult. Thanks!